# One liner to check for file exists

Tags: bash, files

Objective: Check for presence of backup .tgz file containing today's date; output 1 for OK, 0 for no file.

I'm a sucker for one liners :) 
For example in PHP (and pretty much similar in Javascript), in various scenarios I like to do something like

```
<?php
echo (date("d")==1)?"Monday":"Not Monday";
?>
```

Is there similar syntax in Bash? I know how to check for presence of a regular file using -f FILENAME, I only want the command to print 1 or 0 :)

Comment: Why isn't `-f` enough then? That already returns 0 or 1. Do you want the 0 or 1 to be _printed_ or _returned_?

Comment: @terdon that would be printed

Comment: @DavDav "I'm a sucker for one liners" You do not need a line break after `<?php`, and it is advised not to use `?>` at the end of a PHP program.

Answer (score 37):

You can simply do this :

```
#to check if it's a regular file
[ -f "/you/file.file" ] && echo 1 || echo 0
#to check if a file exist
[ -e "/you/file.file" ] && echo 1 || echo 0
```

In shell this charater `[` means test,  `-e` if file exists `]` end of test `&&` if command return true execute the command after, `||` if command return false execute command after.
This should work in `shell` and `bash`

Comment: It's important to know that if the 'true' command fails, the 'false' command will be executed too

Comment: It's a good idea to use `if ... fi` instead of `x && y || z`. see explanation in [bash pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3)

Answer (score 24):

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ]; then echo "File not found!"; else echo "file found"; fi
```

Comment: It should be noted (since the type of person asking a question like this might not think about it) that `-f` will only alert you of the existence of files you are allowed to see. If you don't have sufficient permissions on a directory, you can't see files within it, even if you specify the full path of the file.

Comment: Thanks for input - I am aware of this. In the specific case at hand, the user running the script has sufficient permissions in the particular folder.

Answer (score 9):

### With `zsh`:

```
(){echo $#} *"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"*.tgz(DN)
```

Would output the number of files in the current directory whose name contains the current date in YYYY-mm-dd format and end in `.tgz` as a decimal number. Replace `(DN)` with `(DN[1])` if you want only 0 or 1.

To use as the condition in an `if` statement, you can do:

```
if ()(($#)) *"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"*.tgz(DN); then
   echo found
else
   echo none found
fi
```

### In `bash`

the equivalent could be:

```
(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; set -- *"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"*.tgz; echo "$#")
```

(replace `"$#"` with `"$(($#>0))"` to get 0 or 1).

and

```
if (shopt -s nullglob dotglob; set -- *"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"*.tgz; (($#))); then
   echo found
else
   echo none found
fi
```

### With `ksh93`:

```
(FIGNORE='@(.|..)'; set -- ~(N)*"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"*.tgz; echo "$#")
```

and

```
if (FIGNORE='@(.|..)'; set -- ~(N)*"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"*.tgz; (("$#"))); then...
```

## POSIXly

```
ls -qA | grep -c "$(date +%Y-%m-%d).*\.tgz$"
```

for the count.

```
ls -qA | grep -q "$(date +%Y-%m-%d).*\.tgz$"; echo "$(($? == 0))"
```

for 0 or 1 and:

And:

```
if ls -qA | grep -q "$(date +%Y-%m-%d).*\.tgz$"; then...
```

Though the common wisdom is not to parse the output of `ls`, here with `-q`, we're making sure there's one file per line and the replacing of non-printable characters with `?` shouldn't affect the `grep`ing for our pattern so it should be relatively safe.

You may see differences if the file names contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters. One advantage is that you'll get an error message if the current directory is no readable.

Comment: The question _explicitly_ mentions bash, it is tagged `bash`, and it was like that from the beginning. Why is your main answer about a different shell no one asked for?

Comment: @pipe, the answer covers bash as well. The answer is not only for the OP, not everybody's restricted to using `bash`. Even the OP could consider switching to a different shell.

Comment: @pipe I'm a fan of zsh. Every bash user should consider switching IMHO.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Write a blog about it. This is absolutely the wrong place for fanboyism.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this command:

```
test -e *$(date).tgz && echo 1 || echo 0
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually _return_ 1 or 0. It _prints_ 1 or 0 which is a different thing. If you want to return 1 or 0, just use the `test -e` part and forget the rest. The `test` command already returns 0 or 1 depending on its status.

Comment: Except that _test_ returns the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: how would this behave if there were more than one file matching the wildcard?

Answer (score 4):

As yet another variant, if you knew the exact format of the filename you were looking for you could use

```
[ ! -f FILENAME ]; echo $?
```

or

```
echo `[ ! -f FILENAME ]` $?
```

however this couldn't cope with wildcards, so files ending in .tgz containing today's date would need something more complex, such as

```
echo $( for entry in *$(date --rfc-3339=date)*.tgz; do [ -f "$entry" ] && exit 1; done; exit 0 ) $?
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for Bash, but if you're looking for any command line program that will work, I recommend Python:

```
python -c "import os; exists = os.path.isfile('myFile.txt'); print(int(exists))"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls filename 2> /dev/null && echo 1 || echo 0
```

Or, if you want it in a variable

```
EXISTS=$(ls filename 2> /dev/null && echo 1 || echo 0)
```

Comment: What is the advantage of `ls` compared to `test`?